# Create FAST Materialised View in Oracle 10g with ROWID

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-10g, materialized-view

I want to create FAST refresh the below Materialized view through rowID method.

```
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW XXARG_ACC_ANALYSIS
  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
  AS SELECT   gjb.name "Batch_Name",
         gjs.user_je_source_name "Source",
         gjc.user_je_category_name "Category",
         gjh.default_effective_date "GL_Date",
         gjh.je_header_id,
         gjl.je_line_num "Line_Number",
         gcc.segment1,
         gcc.segment4,
         gcc.segment3,
         gjs.je_source_name,
         gjc.je_category_name,
            gcc.segment1
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment2
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment3
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment4
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment5
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment6
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment7
         || '.'
         || gcc.segment8
            "Account_Code", gjl.accounted_dr "Dr_Amount",gjl.accounted_cr "Cr_Amount",
         gjl.description "Line_Description",
         gjh.description "Journal_Description",
         flv.meaning "Batch_Status",
         fft1.description "Branch",
         fft2.description "LOB",
         fft3.description "GL_Account",
         GLGJB.rowid "A", GLGJH.rowid "B", GLGJL.rowid "C", GLGJC.rowid "D", GLGJS.rowid "E", GLGCC.rowid "F",
         AFLV.rowid "G", AFIFS.rowid "H", AFIFSE.rowid "I", AFFV.rowid "J", AFFVT.rowid "K"
  FROM   APPS.gl_je_batches gjb,
         APPS.gl_je_headers gjh,
         APPS.gl_je_lines gjl,
         APPS.GL_JE_CATEGORIES_TL gjc,
         APPS.GL_JE_SOURCES_TL gjs,
         APPS.gl_code_combinations gcc,
         APPS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES flv,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures ffs1,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments fif1,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values ffv1,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl fft1,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures ffs2,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments fif2,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values ffv2,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl fft2,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures ffs3,
         APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments fif3,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values ffv3,
         APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl fft3,
         GL.GL_JE_BATCHES GLGJB,
         GL.GL_JE_HEADERS GLGJH,
         GL.GL_JE_LINES GLGJL,
         GL.GL_JE_CATEGORIES_TL GLGJC,
         GL.GL_JE_SOURCES_TL GLGJS,
         GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLGCC,
         APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES AFLV,
         APPLSYS.FND_ID_FLEX_STRUCTURES AFIFS,
         APPLSYS.FND_ID_FLEX_SEGMENTS AFIFSE,
         APPLSYS.FND_FLEX_VALUES AFFV,
         APPLSYS.FND_FLEX_VALUES_TL AFFVT
 WHERE       gjh.je_batch_id = gjb.je_batch_id(+)
         AND gjh.je_header_id = gjl.je_header_id(+)
         AND gjh.je_category = gjc.je_category_name
         AND gjh.je_source = gjs.je_source_name
         AND gjh.default_effective_date > '31-MAR-16'
         AND gjl.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
         AND gjb.status = flv.lookup_code
         AND flv.lookup_type = 'BATCH_STATUS'
         AND flv.VIEW_APPLICATION_ID = 101
         AND flv.lookup_code = 'P'
         AND ffs1.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND ffs1.id_flex_structure_code = 'ARG_COA'
         AND fif1.id_flex_num = ffs1.id_flex_num
         AND fif1.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND fif1.application_column_name = 'SEGMENT1'
         AND ffv1.flex_value = gcc.segment1
         AND ffv1.flex_value_id = fft1.flex_value_id
         AND fif1.flex_value_set_id = ffv1.flex_value_set_id
         AND ffs2.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND ffs2.id_flex_structure_code = 'ARG_COA'
         AND fif2.id_flex_num = ffs2.id_flex_num
         AND fif2.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND fif2.application_column_name = 'SEGMENT4'
         AND fif2.flex_value_set_id = ffv2.flex_value_set_id
         AND ffv2.flex_value = gcc.segment4
         AND ffv2.flex_value_id = fft2.flex_value_id
         AND ffs3.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND ffs3.id_flex_structure_code = 'ARG_COA'
         AND fif3.id_flex_num = ffs3.id_flex_num
         AND fif3.id_flex_code = 'GL#'
         AND fif3.application_column_name = 'SEGMENT3'
         AND fif3.flex_value_set_id = ffv3.flex_value_set_id
         AND ffv3.flex_value = gcc.segment3
         AND ffv3.flex_value_id = fft3.flex_value_id;`
```

**NOTE:** I have created MLOGS for the base tables GL.GL_JE_BATCHES, GL.GL_JE_HEADERS, GL.GL_JE_LINES, GL.GL_JE_CATEGORIES_TL, GL.GL_JE_SOURCES_TL, GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS, APPLSYS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES, APPLSYS.FND_ID_FLEX_STRUCTURES, APPLSYS.FND_ID_FLEX_SEGMENTS, APPLSYS.FND_FLEX_VALUES,APPLSYS.FND_FLEX_VALUES_TL.

We have created synonyms from the above base tables to APPS schema. APPS.gl_je_batches, APPS.gl_je_headers, APPS.gl_je_lines, APPS.GL_JE_CATEGORIES_TL, APPS.GL_JE_SOURCES_TL, APPS.gl_code_combinations, APPS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES, APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures, APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments, APPS.fnd_flex_values, APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl, APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures, APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments, APPS.fnd_flex_values, APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl, APPS.fnd_id_flex_structures, APPS.fnd_id_flex_segments, APPS.fnd_flex_values, APPS.fnd_flex_values_tl.

But I'm getting the below error

`AND flv.VIEW_APPLICATION_ID = 101
                                       *
ERROR at line 76:
ORA-12052: cannot fast refresh materialized view APPS.XXARG_ACC_ANALYSIS`

Or if I try to do Complete refresh, it displays me the below error

`AND flv.VIEW_APPLICATION_ID = 101
                                       *
ERROR at line 76:
ORA-01114: IO error writing block to file 201 (block # 4154889)
ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Manager
ORA-01114: IO error writing block to file 201 (block # 4154889)
ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Manager`

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so 2 problems here:

1. `ORA-29701` this may be caused by a bug, permission issue with the executables or other environmental errors, such as deleting socket files from the tmp directory. First investigate this.
2. `ORA-12052: cannot fast refresh materialized view`. For this:

[Diagnosing ORA-12004 Refresh Fast Cannot be Used (Doc ID 179469.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=179469.1)

> ### 1.8 Materialized View References Synonyms or Views
>
> Fast refreshable materialized views can be created based on master
>   tables and  master materialized views only. Materialized views based
>   on a synonym or a view  must be complete refreshed.  This actually is
>   a consequence of the cause  discussed in Section 1.3.  **From 8.1.6
>   onwards, use of a synonym or a view in  place of a direct reference to
>   a master table renders the materialized view  complex, and thus it
>   cannot be fast refreshed.**  This can be seen if a direct  attempt is
>   made to create the materialized view as fast refreshable when it 
>   references synonyms or views.

But instead of manually searching for reasons why fast refresh is not possible, let the database do the work:

Run `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlxmv.sql` to create the `MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE`.

Use [DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#CEGGEHHC) to explain the mview:

```
begin
  DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW ('create materialized view ....');
end;
/
```

After that you can find the reason why fast refresh is not possible in `MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE`.